# onCreate trigger firebase cloud function

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

So, I made a functions that triggers using the database realtime trigger "onCreate", the reference path is "something/{userId}". What happened is that whenever there's a new child inside "something", the event triggers but I want that the events trigger when a new child is created inside "something/{userId}" and not in "something".

This is what I have right now, but don't work as I would like.

```
functions.database
  .ref('/stripe_customers/{customerId}/sources/{cardId}')
  .onCreate
```

Comment: It triggers when new  data is added under cardid

Answer (score 2):

```
functions.database
  .ref('/stripe_customers/{customerId}')
  .onCreate
```

This is how I have a similar one working. Hope it helps. You just need to change the database path level that you want to track.